# Python how to capture a pattern composed of a number followed by any of multiple measuring units

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a pattern from a long string. The pattern is composed of three parts in the following sequence:
1- One or two digit number that may include a decimal point.
2- A measuring unit or a symbol for a measuring unit which could be one of the following [ft, feet, foot, inch, ', "].
3- A word that follows the measuring unit, such as height, long, width, t,, w, l, etc...

**This what I have done:**

```
import re
text = '''..text....it approx. 2.0 ft long 335.1 feet wide 9.5' high and located.....text...'''
matched_list = re.findall(r'''[0-9\.]+\s?ft\s?\w+|[0-9\.]+\s?feet\s?\w+|[0-9\.]+\s?foot\s?\w+|[0-9\.]+\s?'\s?\w+|[0-9\.]+\s?"\s?\w+''', text)
print(matched_list )
```

**This is the result of the code:**
['2.5 ft long', '335.1 feet wide', "9.5' high"]

**There are some problems in my code**:

1- It captured numbers with more than two digits. I need to capture numbers with one or two digits only that may include a decimal point.
2- The way I solved the problem is tedious. I think there should be a better way to achieve my goal. I am new to regular expression.
3- What if the number was in the form of a whole and fraction, such as 2 1/5 ft rather than 2.5 ft.

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be tedious, but using `\w+` might match more than you would allow.

For matching 1 or 2 digits, you could assert a whitespace boundary to the left, or assert not a digit.

Then use 2 alternations to list all the allowed like ft, feet and height, long etc.. and add a word boundary `\b` to the end to prevent a partial match.

For the `2 1/5` part, you could also use an alternation to match either a decimal part or a space and 2 times digits with a `/` in between.

```
(?<!\S)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+|\s+\d+/\d+)?\s*(?:ft|feet|foot|inch|['"])\s+(?:height|long|width|[twl]|wide|high)\b
```

In parts:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `(?:\.\d+|\s+\d+/\d+)?` Match either a decimal part or 1+ whitespace chars and digits/digits
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?:ft|feet|foot|inch|['"])` Match any of the alternatives
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:height|long|width|[twl]|wide|high)\b` Match any of the alternatives followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiaDcz/1)

```
import re
text = ("..text....it approx. 2.0 ft long 335.1 feet wide 9.5' high and located.....text...\n"
    "2 1/5 ft high")
matched_list = re.findall(r'''(?<!\S)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+|\s+\d+/\d+)?\s*(?:ft|feet|foot|inch|['"])\s*(?:height|long|width|[twl]|wide|high)\b''', text)
print(matched_list)
```

Output

```
['2.0 ft long', "9.5' high", '2 1/5 ft high']
```